# reverse query n level to first level

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oracle

in my project i have 3 level.

1. category
2. subcategory
3. product

in product table i have foreign key of subcategory and in subcategory i have foreign key of category.
if i need category of product i retrive subcategory_id the compare with category so on.but it is long method for n how i design my database for n level.
i method is that i put category and subcategory id as foreign key but i personally dislike it.
any other design logic, concept or query.[image]

Comment: You could have a category table with a nullable parent_id column, and maybe a "level" int field. So you could just find categories related to the parent by parent_id, or find all top levels where parent_id IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

Use a table to store the hierarchical data with the category ID referencing the ID of the same table and then use hierarchical queries to descend the structure as required.

So, for Oracle:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products (
  id          NUMBER(12,0)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              CONSTRAINT products__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name        VARCHAR2(50)
              NOT NULL,
  category_id NUMBER(12,0)
              CONSTRAINT products__category_id__fk REFERENCES products ( id )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next tables structure here:

1. Categories table (each category have own id, name and possible parent category id): MySQL code provided for example

```
    CREATE TABLE Categories (
        id int primary key auto_increment,
        name varchar(64),
        parent_id int
    );
```

2. Products table with foreign key to Categories:

```
    CREATE TABLE Products (
        id int primary key auto_increment,
        name varchar(64),
        category_id int,
        foreign key (category_id) references Categories (id)
    );
```

This DB structure give you ability to not limited sub categories with 2 tables only

Here [SQL live fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=908cae1e43d58567741709c8ef67a8a9&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80) where it can be tested